# What would be the jquery equivalent of 'Dive into python'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I need to , well, dive into client side programming.  Is there an equivalent to 'Dive into python' for jquery?

I see that jquery 1.4 has been released.  Does this change anything w.r.t answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well python is a language and jQuery is a framework, so I'll give you one for javascript and then you can move to jQuery:

This book should be a required read for front end devs:

[JavaScript: The Good Parts  by Douglas Crockford](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

Then:

[The jQuery Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596159773)

This one is a pretty awesome dive into all the different aspects of programming real world applications with jQuery, whereas "Dive into Python" and "JS The Good Parts" are more like poignant language overviews.

Comment: The Crockford book will give a lot of useful background on JavaScript that will make using jQuery effectively a lot easier.

Comment: Crockford has a number of lectures and articles online that you can peruse until your book gets here.  http://javascript.crockford.com/

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery's main documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) is quite good. You might start with [How jQuery works](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works).
If you have a certain problem and you google for it, you mostly find plenty of tutorials.

Comment: I'm thinking this is the correct answer, with a new jquery version out.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. An API reference to a framework is hardly an equivalent to "Dive Into Python." If I'm not mistaken, that would more closely match up with, say, the Python Documentation: http://www.python.org/doc/